# Angular 7 Unable to get http headers

Tags: angular

I trying to do some scraping without python, just a simple http get request from web angular app, the problem is the response, I need gain access to the headers, to get the **csrftoken** header.

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.
```

Code:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

const r = this.http.request<HttpResponse<Object>>('GET', 'https://www.example.com', {
  headers: headers
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190620/angular-2-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-at-json-parse)

Comment: Use the browser to see what you are actually getting back, chances are its xml or html and not json.

Comment: Yes, I trying to request a html page, only for extract the headers, and then with that data I will go for the endpoint that have the data that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server need to expose `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to get access to one that you need from js.

If your response is not a valid json then try using observe property (`observe: 'response'`) on request to prevent angular to parse it as json

Comment: With the CORS theme, I'm using a workaround for the moment, some plugin that chrome have, and  the other part is I set that option and I still have the response processed as JSON by the method.

Comment: I I followed this guide also: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: The combination of the observer and responseType properties did the trick! and yes as you mention I need set Access-Control-Expose-Headers for get access to top level headers from the web client, but in my case, the in the body, there is a meta tag that have csrftoken defined, so that work for me to! Many thanks for helping me find the solution!